# How to send multiple items to another page for printing (using html)?

Tags: html

How to send multiple items  to another page for printing (using html). The items include input texts filled in by users.

I am doing one item per html page. Each item requires some inputs from the user.

How can I print multiple items chosen by the user and print them in one page?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the value of multiple input items from the same form on the same page?

Comment: I am using html, for instance, page 1 I have description of an item and also the input from the user. and there will be a home button and add item button at the bottom of the page. My question is if a user had chosen item in page one and another item in page 2, is it possible to send all the descriptions from page 1 and 2 and altogether with the input be sent to another page for a print out?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using `database`, then save the values in a `table`. 
OR
You can use `session` to store data which can be accessed from any page until it ends.
OR
You can pass values as `QueryString` along with URL.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("printBut").onclick=function() {
    var w = window.open("","newwin");
    if (!w) {
      alert("sorry you need to allow this page to popup a window");
      return;
    }
    var html='<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">';
    html += "You entered "+document.getElement("someField").value;
    html += "Details "+document.getElement("someDiv").innerHTML;
    hmtl +='</body>';
    w.document.write(html);
    w.document.close();
  }
}
```

assuming a button with id="printBut", a field with id="someField" and a div with id="someDiv"

If you have page1, page2, page3 and need bits from each, you will need to pass the data to each page and have this script on the last page

You can get at the data using

```
location="page2.html?val="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElement("someField").value);
```

and on page 2 have

```
var someFieldValue = location.search.split("val=")[1];
```